# Is there a way to retrieve a FTP/cPanel accounts password using WHM?

Tags: web-hosting, cpanel, ftp, password

I know you can reset an accounts password with WHM, but does any one know a way to retrieve an existing one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sadly without running a brute force which I can't advise on you can not since cPanel is normally setup to use ProFTPD and PureFTP both of these servers used hashed passwords and they are not viewable in any form - if it's your server just reset the password.

Comment: Ah thought it would be the case - thanks. If anyone's interested I found a sneaky way to view the password if you already have it saved in FileZilla but have forgotten it: export the Site Manager Entries as an xml, open in a text editor, search for the entry you want to retreive the password for

Comment: Many FTP clients save the passwords in text form, and there is even software that reveals behind the *****. Nothing new m8 ;)

Answer (score 1):

This should not be possible from a security point of view. The password should not be stored in a retrievable format. I have not heard of any issues with cPanels security in respect to passwords so I would assume this is impossible.